# Mysql multiple join delete missing a row

Tags: mysql, sql

When I run this query :

```
                DELETE
                    entreprise,
                    entreprise_detail,
                    entr_bail
                FROM entreprise
                LEFT JOIN entreprise_detail
                ON entreprise_detail.entr_id = entreprise.id
                LEFT JOIN entr_bail
                ON entr_bail.formalite_id = entreprise.formalite_id
                WHERE entreprise.formalite_id = :formalite_id
```

The 2 rows from "entreprise" and "entreprise_detail" are deleted, but the row from entr_bail is never deleted.

I checked the database to see if an ID was wrong but everything is ok, so i'm starting to ask myself if I have understood the way joined delete works.

Is there anything wrong with this ?
Thanks a lot

Comment: A LEFT JOIN in a DELETE is unlikely

Comment: Yes, I tried JOIN and INNER JOIN but results were bad. Look like must read more about this

Comment: 'bad' is not very useful for us.

Comment: Forget this, this code is working and the error was in fact really stupid (entr_bail was deleted but inserted just after >_<).

Comment: If I use JOIN instead of LEFT JOIN, is the query safe ? I'm really worried about things that could happen (like a user deleting another user's data) and I have the feeling that this is not a safe code (my SQL is a bit hazardous)

Comment: If you have those sorts of concerns, then you shouldn't be granting those sorts of privileges to your users. Consider having a 'deleted' or 'hidden' flag that the user can UPDATE to '1'. That way you can always undo changes. But for further help...

Comment: If you like, consider following this simple two-step course of action: 1. If you have not already done so, provide proper DDLs (and/or an sqlfiddle) so that we can more easily replicate the problem. 2. If you have not already done so, provide a desired result set that corresponds with the information provided in step 1.

Comment: Didn't know sqlfiddle, will think about it next time. For now, I will keep things how they are, and improve my SQL before asking more questions. Thanks for your answers

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
DELETE entreprise, entreprise_detail, entr_bail
FROM entreprise,  entreprise_detail, entr_bail
WHERE 
 entreprise_detail.entr_id = entreprise.id AND
 entr_bail.formalite_id = entreprise.formalite_id AND
 entreprise.formalite_id = :formalite_id
```

Comment: This is PERFECT ! I didn't know this was possible to do this without a JOIN. Thanks

Comment: Perfect? This looks like a step backwards to me - oh, and this IS a join BTW

Comment: Sorry, false alert. In fact this is exactly the same result, and the problem came from elsewhere. If you have a good and recent reading about this kind of operation I would  be grateful.